# Why you can't summon face-up monsters in defense position?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I know it is the rule you can only summon in attack position or set (face-down defense position), but I'm curious about why it is a rule that you have to place all the defense position's monsters face-down.

Is there some overpowered strategy if I'm allowed to put face-up defense position's monsters or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

> I know it is the rule you can only summon in attack position or set (face-down defense position)

To correct on your phrase, one can only **Normal Summon** in Face-up attack position.

Unless otherwise restricted, **you can *Special Summon* in Face-up defense position.**

---

The actual reason for doing so I guess is something only Konami knows. If I were to conjecture on the reason, I would say that it is because **not only is your monster in defense, which could be tactical advantage, but you will also be able to activate its effects**.

To prevent this abuse, the rules force you to Normal summon in Attack position (possibly a disadvantage, or at least open for battle damage) if you wish to activate your monster's effect. Think of it as "if you want to activate this effect you have to take some risks".

On the other hand, I also think this could be a "Legacy" rule, one that has lost its original impact, as now there are many ways to summon in face-up defense position (one barely Normal summons now days). Perhaps Konami decided to let it be, to prevent possible abuse.

Comment: It's never been a "Legacy Rule" in the real-world card game, but the characters in the *Yu-Gi-Oh!* manga and anime series sometimes summon monsters into face-up defense position to speed things up for the sake of drama. In most cases, there's no reason they wouldn't have wanted to set the monster face-down, but it saves a few turns of back and forth if they just reveal their monsters right away.

Comment: @Thunderforge by Legacy I mean old rule that perhaps could be modified/removed but is preserved. The anime point is a good one, that was one of many things done to speed up or slow down the pace of the series. That being said, the main reason for the rule is, as stated in the answer, to prevent effect monsters from activating their effs without risking some Battle Damage.